# Insert INTO from one table to another and change column values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Office access and I have a task to move out the table to another table and change column values.

I have table like:

```
ID   NAME     DIRECTOR     UNIVERSITY
1    Banana   Apple        KTU
2    Pear     Orange       KTU
3    Tomato   Cucumber     VU
```

And I have another one with:

```
ID     UNIVERSITY
1      KTU
2      VU
```

What I am trying to do is to get new table into new file that would look like this:

```
    ID    NAME     DIRECTOR     UNIVERSITYID
     1    Banana   Apple        1
     2    Pear     Orange       1
     3    Tomato   Cucumber     2
```

My SQL code looks like this, but it doesn't get me the result I want:

```
INSERT INTO Fakultetas IN 'C:\Users\NeuTronas\Desktop\NaujaDB.accdb'
SELECT DISTINCT a.[Unikalus ID] AS ID,
                a.Pavadinimas AS Pavadinimas,
                a.Dekanas AS Dekanas,
                a.Lokacija AS Lokacija,
                b.ID AS UniversitetoID
FROM Fakultetas AS a
  INNER JOIN [C:\Users\NeuTronas\Desktop\NaujaDB.accdb].Universitetai AS b
    ON a.Universitetas = b.Univesitetas;
```

It's a bit different table but if it were like one in example it would be:

```
INSERT INTO NewTableName IN 'C:\Users\NeuTronas\Desktop\NaujaDB.accdb'
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID AS ID,
                a.Name AS Name,
                a.Director AS Director,
                a,
                b.ID AS UniversityID
FROM OldTableName AS a
  INNER JOIN [C:\Users\NeuTronas\Desktop\NaujaDB.accdb].SecondTableName AS b
    ON a.Universitetas = b.Univesitetas;
```

Comment: exactly HOW is this not working?

Comment: When I try to run this SQL line, the program asks me to Enter a parameter value, when I enter a random University, I get duplicated values for example: 3 bananas with different universities. It's still SQL and MySQL is the most popular one

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this in the NaujaDB.accdb database? I.e. create a new empty table in NaujaDB.accdb with the fields you need and call it Fakultetas. Import/link to the other Fakultetas table that has the data you need, then write your append query in NaujaDB.accdb. You won't have to reference any file paths and file names this way.

Comment: You want 4 columns, but select 5?

Comment: in your second SQL statement, after selecting `a.Director`, you select just `a`... shouldn't this be `a.myFieldName`? `a` is the aliased name for the `OldTableName` table.

Comment: It's just rewriting mistake to make it more understandable in you, I have bigger table but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are really looking for but your could do something like the following:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.NAME, a.DIRECTOR, b.UNIVERSITYID
INTO FakultetasTemp
FROM Fakultetas a
INNER JOIN SecondTableName b 
   ON a.Universitetas = b.Univesitetas
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this
1st you make a copy of your banana table (lets call it table:a)

```
SELECT a.* INTO a_1
FROM a;
```

2nd you run an update query  on the copied table (a1) with data from the university table(b)

```
UPDATE a_1 INNER JOIN b ON a_1.University = b.UNIVERSITY SET a_1.University = [b]![Id];
```